# Using PHP to parse a Google Calendar XML - End date is off by a day

Tags: php, xml, google-calendar-api, utc

I am trying to make a webpage and have the next three events on a Google Calendar show up on the home page. I have been using this PHP (http://james.cridland.net/code/google-calendar.html) to access my XML feed and format it into HTML.

The problem I'm having is that for some reason a new day starts at 11am. For example if my Google Calendar has an event from 10am on the 20th of December that lasts an hour, my PHP output will show an event that starts at 10am on the 20th which ends at 11am on the 21st. Otherwise it is working fine.

I have set my time to local (New Zealand) time on my Google Calendar account, and in PHP using `date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");`

The horrible line that calculates the finish date is

```
$gCalDateEnd = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)));
```

where $dateformat is a string with the date format.

The Google Calendar XML gives a start and finish time of

```
2011-12-22T10:00:00.000+13:00
2011-12-23T11:00:00.000+13:00
```

respectively, and the PHP is calculating a timeframe of 10.00am 22 December 2011 to 2.00pm 23 December 2011.

Whats going on?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is indeed horrible:

```
$gCalDateEnd = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)+
    date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)));
```

[`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can handle this type of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates just fine. This code-fragment is probably written under the assumption that `strtotime` dismisses the timezone and returns the datetime in UTC and therefore the timezone "correction" needs to be calculated manually - that's what the `+date("Z", ...)` stands for (with "Z" the second parameter - the timestamp - is actually ignored).

So in your example 13 hours are added to your dates. And `10:00 + 13:00 = 23:00` (11 pm) which is still on the same day, but `11:00 + 13:00 = 24:00` (12 am) which is actually `00:00` on a new day.

So the correct way to convert the date is:

```
$gCalDateEnd = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime));
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something like that. From what I could read in the changelog of his code it sounded like he was trying use the +date('Z',...) to account for daylight savings time, but the XML seemed to show that Google already does this with the +13.

Answer (score 1):

Try the zend framework for google calendar(It worked for me better than reinventing the wheel): http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html (look at the examples, they're quite easy and helpful)

Comment: I had looked into using that initially but was scared that I would make the site too complex to be maintained in the future (its for a non-profit club so most likely will be looked after by someone with minimal skills). But after having a look at the examples it doesn't look too bad, I might give it a go. Thanks for the suggestion!